# Finding independent "clusters" in a matrix

Tags: clustering, matrix

I've called my question "clustering" but I am not sure if that's the right term. Imagine my matrix looks like this:

```
[ 0.  ,  0.92,  0.  ,  0.85,  0.  ]
[ 0.92,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.89,  0.  ]
[ 0.85,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.89,  0.  ]
[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]
[ 0.  ,  0.89,  0.  ,  0.89,  0.  ]
```

What I am after is not a single clustering/dendrogram of indices, I am after extracting largest possible rectangles from the matrix (by re-arranging X/Y indices).

For example, from the above I am expecting to get:

```
[ 0.92,  0.89,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]
[ 0.85,  0.89,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]
[ 0.  ,  0.85,  0.92,  0.  ,  0.  ]
[ 0.  ,  0.89,  0.89,  0.  ,  0.  ]
[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]
```

However, I expect each cluster to be identified, even if it is not possible to show them all in a single matrix.

What would be an algorithm I should be after? I've tried various clustering algorithms and they give me best single clustering, not focusing on the best individuals (which are mutually incompatible).

Comment: Please explain in your question what you mean by a "rectangle" in the matrix and what criteria you would use to divide one large one into two or more smaller ones.

Comment: Rectangle of non-zero values. For example, if there is a way to re-organise the matrix to get 3x3 non-zero rectangle, I would like to know the order of indices on X/Y. Also, if there is another 3x3 rectangle which is mutually exclusive with the first one, I would like to see it as a separate solution.

Comment: Exactly how do you determine whether one rectangle is "larger" than another?  For instance, how would a $2\times 4$ rectangle compare to a $3\times 3$ rectangle?

Comment: I think the overall "area" would be good to start with, but eventually I would like to bias the selection towards symmetric dimensions

Comment: Another issue is whether you want to optimize the overall solution (in some sense) or whether you want to proceed in a greedy manner to find the largest rectangle and then recursively obtain largest rectangles subject to fixing the rows and columns of all rectangles found so far. As far as "each cluster to be identified" goes, that's going to be a *huge* number in general.  It will include all individual nonzero cells, all pairs of cells that can be brought into proximity via permutations, etc.  Is that what you really need?

Comment: I am not interested in overall solution - literally just finding largest individual rectangles is my goal. The matrix itself is not particularly large (63x63) and has around 50% zeros (it also is symmetric if it helps). The optimisation goal is to find symmetric / close to symmetric rectangles of continuous values.

Comment: This is further confusing because the examples in the question are not symmetric. Please edit the question to include the information currently found only in these comments and to make its examples reflect the kinds of data you really have.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [Biclustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering), which aims at identifying rows and columns *at the same time* with a similar value or pattern.

This is closely related to subspace clustering, but you seem to be more interested in the rearrangement than in complex patterns.

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for. Is there any off-the-shelf approach I can use to solve this? To explain what I am trying to do - I've got a matrix with interaction scores between agents (and 0 for non-interaction). I am after getting sub-matrices that would contain no zeros in order to find groups I can work with. Each result is independent thus I am not looking at just one solution

Comment: Plenty. Cheng and Church for example. You'll need to try out a few, to figure out which one matches your intuitions best. Some are designed for binarized matrixes; so CC might not be the best choice for you. It's common in gene expression analysis that the numerical value is not reliable, but you can tell whether it is "high" or "low".

Comment: Thank you very much! will start reading .. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs597F/Articles/biclustering_of_expression_data.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your question is trivially transformed into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931735/finding-largest-rectangle-in-2d-array) problem.

Once the largest triangle is found, transfer it to the top left and recursively run the program on the inner sub-triangles.

Comment: Please explain this "trivial" transformation, given that arbitrary permutations of rows and columns appear to be allowable.  As far as I can tell the problem you reference is only superficially related to this one and its solution method is not going to be helpful in general.

Comment: Ahh, I see your point. I was thinking of an approach to find the non-zero clusters in a matrix. I was thinking we could find the largest cluster of zeros, say it is of size $n_{1} \times n_{2}$. I can now use this clustering algorithm recursively as follows: Use it on the two sub-rectangles above and below the red rectangle and on the sub rectangle on the right etc.

Comment: Conceivably this could be a solution or part of one, depending on what the OP really intends.  Let's wait for clarification.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure it's the same - I first need to find the right permutation of indices to be able to search for the rectangle in the first place.

Comment: Even in the best setting, the results are vague. As whuber states, largest rectangle in this context is pretty meaningless. In your example, for instance would you say the largest rectangular blocks are two $2 \times 2$ blocks or one $4 \times 3$ block? This ambiguity will persist on rearrangement too and hence I simply decided to find the largest blocks with non-zero entries (or a few zero entries depending on your termination criteria in the program)

Comment: I am looking at individuals - therefore largest continuous rectangle would be the 4×3